# Base tag won't work

Tags: html, base-tag

For some reason that I don't know the base tag at http://www.galaxy-os.kd.io?/dev (which is a PHP echo of http://galaxy-os.koding.com) doesn't work. I don't know why this is and it's really annoying. (FYI Koding.com have announced a new version with .kd.io domains which is why I'm doing this)

Comment: The base is in the source; I don't understand the question.

Comment: @redditor there is a problem with it though, if you go to the website there are is no style or function but there should be stylesheets and scripts (they don't work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links to the stylesheet and js file seem to be correct and they both work fine if I open them up manually (which means that the base tag does in fact work), but the links give a 403 error when loaded by the site itself. Maybe there is some cross domain restriction in effect?

[image: Chrome console]

Comment: Thanks for the help, it's working now (it was just Koding being buggy since it's still in beta).

Comment: Ah no, it's not working still. I'll eventually copy over the files though, so it's not too much of a problem. Thanks for help again :D